# ListView doesn't wrap content after child changes visibility

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have a ListView whose children toggle visibility on clicked. Each item has two children and only one is visible at a time, the other is `gone`, If the item is clicked the visibilities of its children are toggled.

The quite unfortunate thing is that one child is taller than the other so the height of the listview needs to be altered at each toggle but this doesn't happen. The height stays fixed.

I have tried playing with LayoutParams but got nothing out of it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after you handle the GONE/VISIBLE events?

Comment: @NKN just tried it, didn't work

Comment: There's a thing I don't get: you're probably defining a customized row layout, when you view it in the graphic preview is the row rendered as it should? You should add your customized layout code.

Comment: @NKN the preview of the Layout are fine. The heights are set to wrap_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot and a lot of trial and error, I managed to get this to work simple by altering the LayoutParams of the listview after changing the visibility of the views.

```
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.getParent();
 layout.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 ((ListView) layout.getParent()).getLayoutParams().height =
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Note that an item in my ListView looks like this

```
<LineaLayout>
    <LinearLayout
     onclick="alterVisibility">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
     onclick="alterVisibility"
     visibility="gone">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```